# How to simplify simple statement in typescript or js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to simplify this expression but don't know how. There has to be a way to have the same expression without the three conditions.

```
if ( request.Document != null &&
      request.Document != undefined &&
      request.Document != "" )
```

Just for context I am talking something similar to c#'s `!string.isNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: As a a value other than any of those outline is considered truthy when coerced in JS, you can just use `if (request.Document) { ...`

Comment: What will happen if the string is empty ("")? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @MatejDodevski try it, you'll see

Comment: `x != undefined` <-- Don't do this; you should use `typeof x === 'undefined'` instead.

Comment: you can simply write ```if ( request.Document ) { ..... }``` This will return false for empty string, undefined, null and 0 as number

Comment: @MatejDodevski an empty string is falsy.

Comment: @MatejDodevski you may consider `if(request.Document?.trim())` as in `isNullOrWhitespace()`. Besides that, you should get familiar with [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (request.Document) {
  ...
}
```

as `null`, `undefined`, `''` will all return false.

(but `[]`, `{}` or `' '` will return true)

Check the [equality table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) for more info about other values.

Comment: _"but `[]`, `{}` or `' '` will return `true`"_ - right, so to handle those cases methinks it would be sensible to use `if( ( typeof request.Document === 'string' ) && /^\w+$/.test( request.Document ) ) { ... }` (assuming that regex is okay).